# How to await an IAsyncAction method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, uwp

I am trying to use `IAsyncAction` method but on awaiting I am getting an error saying:

> "An await operation can only be used in a async lambda function"

Can anyone help in finding the correct format of returning a async function that doesn't return anything

```
IAsyncAction ICameraHelper.startCameraPreview(CaptureElement PreviewControl)
{
    try
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            await InitializeCameraAsync(PreviewControl);
            RegisterEventHandlers();
        }).AsAsyncAction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. The proximate reason is given in the error message. You are doing an `await` in a synchronous lambda. You have to use an async lambda: `async () => { ... }`. But whether that's what you want or not is not clear.

Comment: `Task.Run( async () =>` yadda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
async IAsyncAction ICameraHelper.startCameraPreview(CaptureElement PreviewControl)
{
    await InitializeCameraAsync(PreviewControl);
    RegisterEventHandlers();
}
```

There is no need to attempt to pass the `InitializeCameraAsync` into the `.Task.Run` method.